# Converting a string of numbers inside an array to a pure integer array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array like ["1,2,3,4"]. I am simply trying to convert the numbers inside this array to a pure integer array like [1,2,3,4].

This is what I have tried so far...

```
var a = ["1,2,3,4"];
var b = a.map(val => val.split(','));
console.log(b); // prints ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
var c = b.map(x => parseInt(x));
console.log(c); // prints [1]
```

Why is c only prints [1], instead of looping through all the elements inside b array and print [1,2,3,4]?

Comment: why do you have array with a string inside? could you have more strings inside? which result do you expect in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> console.log(b); // prints ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

This is not correct, it actually prints `[["1", "2", "3", "4"]]` (a 2d array) as you are mapping a string *in* an array to an array, thus, you still maintain the outer array.

Instead, you can use `.flapMap()` to map the contents of the array that `.split()` returns to the outer container array like so:

```js
var a = ["1,2,3,4"];
var b = a.flatMap(val => val.split(','));
console.log(b); // prints ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
var c = b.map(x => parseInt(x));
console.log(c); // prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Alternatively, you can also use `JSON.parse()` on your string of arrays with `.flatMap` to get an array of numbers like so:

```js
var a = ["1,2,3,4"];
var b = a.flatMap(val => JSON.parse(`[${val}]`));
console.log(b); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

However, do note, `.flatMap()` does currently have [limited browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility), and so, instead, you may want to use `.reduce()` if you have multiple elements:

```js
var a = ["1,2,3,4"];
var b = a.reduce((acc, val) => [...acc, ...val.split(',')], []);
console.log(b); // prints [["1", "2", "3", "4"]]
var c = b.map(x => parseInt(x));
console.log(c); // prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The advantage of using these two (three) methods is that it will work for `a` values where you have multiple beginning strings such as `["1,2,3,4", "5,6,7,8"]` etc...

Comment: Hi @NickParsons, Thanks for taking time to explain the problem in my code, and then explaining your solution. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use `split()` as below

```js
var a = ["1,2,3,4"];
var b = a[0].split(",").map(x=>parseInt(x));
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like that:

```
var a = "1,2,3,4";
var b = a.split(',') // or a[0].split(",") if you really want to use ["1,2,3,4"]
var c = b.map(x => parseInt(x));
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `+` for implicit conversion of string to number

```js
var a = ["1,2,3,4"];
var b = a[0].split(',').map(v=> +v);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Alternative: `a[0].split(",").map(Number)`

Answer (score 0):

You create a nested array by taking an array of a string. This returns an array of arrays.

To overcome nested arrays, you fould flat them in a first step and then map with `Number` as callback

```js
var a = ["1,2,3,4"];
var b = a.flatMap(val => val.split(',')).map(Number);
console.log(b); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```